# Flex make Div A the same height as Div B

Tags: css, flexbox

So I have div A and div B.

I need div A to scale to the exact same height as div B

The two divs sit alongside each other and I need the height of Div A to be the same as B

Here is what I have tried: CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  // div a and div b
  > div {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">text for a</div>
  <div class="b">text for b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If your divs are side by side, then you don't need `flex-direction: column;`,

Comment: if you remove flex-direction:column; your divs are side by side, and, if you add more content into div b you will see that the height remains the same for both divs

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this

the `height` property exists on a div.

Then you can use relative/ absolute heights like

Relative (both inherit from parent)

```css
height: 3rem
```

Absolute (fixed)

```css
height: 3em
```

Comment: the height has got to be fluid, so cant set fixed heights

Comment: It's not necessary to set a fixed height